# Container div with background-color hides table cells

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

I was trying to make a tr hover style that applies a box-shadow effect to the row that you are hovering, and I found out that the solution that I made doesn't work if I put the table inside a div that has a background color. This is clearly because the td has a `z-index : -1`, but that was the only way I found out to make the box-shadow work.

Any ideas how to make the table appear, and keep the box-shadow style when hovering?

I reproduced it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pjz43a52/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the tds have a z-index of -1 so they are being rendered below the container div.

To fix this we should give both the container div and the `<table>` element `position: relative`, and set `.container` to have  `z-index: 0` and `<table>` to have a `z-index: 1`.

These z-indexes will force the table and its children to render above the container.
The td's index will still be below the row, but it will now be displayed above the container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna set the td appear when hover, right?
Just add one more line, reset the z-index more than 0 when you hover.

table tr:hover { z-index: 1; }

Comment: The problem is that the table is not visible. I want it to be visible always. If you comment the div's background color you can check that it works. But I want to keep that background color

Answer (score 0):

Give the table itself a z-index, to create an additional “layer” between the table and the div, that the table cell with the negative z-index can reside in, so that it doesn’t get hidden behind the div background.

```
table {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pjz43a52/6/